# how to set a foreign key in django model?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I want to set a 'app_id'of application model as a foreign key for interviewstable's app_id

```
class application(models.Model):
    app_id = models.IntegerField(max_length=200)
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    odesk_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    client_spent = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    job_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    notes_type = models.CharField(max_length=500)



class interviewtable(models.Model):
    app_id = models.IntegerField(max_length=200)
    interview = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    interview_on = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    interview_notes = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Comment: How about doing Django's official tutorial (and reading the doc) before you have too much bad code to maintain ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
class interviewtable(models.Model):
    app = models.ForeignKey(application)
    interview = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    interview_on = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    interview_notes = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Django with automatically add `id` thus app would be `app_id`.

Also, you don't want to use max_length on integer field. If you want big integer use `BigIntegerField()` Read the documentation properly: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/